# angular project npm modules randomly deleted

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have the weirdest problem I've ever seen with npm where in the middle of running an angular `ng serve`, packages from both node and for angular will randomly go missing. In the middle of a save, the project will suddenly not recompile, and will complain about a missing module. Each time it has been different but so far I have had:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../node_modules/core-js/internals/hidden-keys.js'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internals/is-pure' in '/.../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js/internals'

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '/.../node_modules/minipass-collect/node_modules/minipass/index.js'. 

Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

These have just been errors from the last few days, but issues like this has been happening all. to the point where I need to delete node_modules and reinstall everything via npm at least once a day. I'm thinking the error has more to do with node or NPM than with my Angular set up, as some of these missing packages appear to be node core packages.

I've already tried reinstalling npm globally via `npm install -g npm` and it hasn't helped anything. I'm afraid that I'm going to have to just reinstall node completely.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:** upon further debugging, I'm noticing that the modules missing are always from `@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js/modules`. In addition to losing random modules like 'is-pure', the app will also randomly recompile many times when running `ng serve`

Comment: what IDE do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.45.1

Comment: are you using an antivirus that got in?

Comment: @pbachman I'm running this locally on a Macbook, so no antivirus software as far as I'm aware. I haven't installed anything like that myself

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on, if anyone in the future has the same problem. Turns out the answer has nothing to do with me botching my npm config. I didn't realize that on new Macbooks, any directory in the desktop is automatically managed by iCloud. At some point, probably an older version of the code before I migrated to Angular 9 was syncing the old code into my project. I was able to resolve this issue by changing the name of the parent directory where my project lived from `filename` to `filename.nosync`. adding '.nosync' causes iCloud to ignore syncing for whatever is in that file. I know I should have caught this, but hopefully this will help any mac users in the future who are experiencing similar problems.